# Elasticsearch 2.3 vs elasticsearch 1.7 Java Heap space

Tags: elasticsearch, heap-memory, quadtree

I have two elasticsearch versions running in my machine one is **1.7** and other **2.3**
I am able to index the document in **1.7** version but the same indexing statement throws `u'caused_by': {u'reason': u'Java heap space', u'type': u'out_of_memory_error'}` in **2.3**.

Mapping for **Elasticsearch 2.3**

```
   {
    "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "analyzed"
    },
    "field1": {
        "type": "integer",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "no"
    },
    "field2": {
        "type": "integer",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "no"
    },
    "field3": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "no"
    },
    "field4": {
        "type": "geo_shape",
        "tree": "legacyquadtree",
        "precision": "1mm"
    }
}
```

Mapping for **Elasticsearch 1.7**

```
  {
    "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "analyzed"
    },
    "field1": {
        "type": "integer",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "no"
    },
    "field2": {
        "type": "integer",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "no"
    },
    "field3": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "no"
    },
    "field4": {
        "type": "geo_shape",
        "tree": "quadtree",
        "precision": "1mm"
    }
}
```

The doc structure which is used for indexing is (same for both **2.3** and **1.7**)

```
      {
        "field4":
            {"type": "envelope", "coordinates":
                data},
        "id": id,
        "field1": val1,
        "field2": val2,
        "field3": val3
    }
```

The `JAVA_HEAP_SIZE` specified is default for both the versions.

Answer (score 6):

Try by increasing the JAVA_HEAP_SPACE. it worked for me

1. Open Elasticsearch file from "/etc/sysconfig"

sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch

2.You can change the heap size here

ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g

(The default size is 2gb. You can increase it upto 50% of available ram)